# Why this code throw syntax error unexpected in all function where i invoke more then one -> function

Tags: php

Why this code throw

> syntax error, unexpected **'->'** (**T_OBJECT_OPERATOR**), expecting ',' or ';'

php 7.1

```php
<?php
class TestHtml
{
    public function Send() { return $this; }
    public function Dispose() { return $this; }
    public function ToString() { return 'Done'; }
}
echo new TestHtml->Send()->Dispose()->ToString(); // there error 
?>
```

Comment: `echo (new TestHtml())->Send()->Dispose()->ToString();`

Comment: More brackets are always the answer

Comment: Thank you all for good question answer it's so helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot make sense of this. It cannot figure out that the first part is a call to a constructor. Use parens.

```
<?php
class TestHtml
{
    public function Send() { return $this; }
    public function Dispose() { return $this; }
    public function ToString() { return 'Done'; }
}
echo (new TestHtml)->Send()->Dispose()->ToString(); // there error
```

Alternatively, you could create the object first, then call the other functions.

```
$object = new TestHtml;
echo $object->Send()->Dispose()->ToString();
```

And just for fun, you could make a static function to create the class.

```
<?php
class TestHtml
{
    public function Send() { return $this; }
    public function Dispose() { return $this; }
    public function ToString() { return 'Done'; }
    public static function make() { return new self; }
}
echo TestHtml::make()->Send()->Dispose()->ToString();
```